# How to set borderstyle of a datagridview column at runtime (.Net Framework 4.0)?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a readonly datagridview that is bound to a datasource. It has two columns. Now I want the first column to have no cell borderstyle; and the second one to have 'All' (i.e. all sides of the cell shall have a border) as cell borderstyle. Before binding the datagridview to the datasource, I'm writing something like mentioned below but it's taking no effect. Assume the column in question is named DisplayName.

```
Dim newStyle As New DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle()
With newStyle
.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single
.Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single
.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single
.Right = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single
End With

DisplayName.CellTemplate.AdjustCellBorderStyle(newStyle, newStyle, True, True, True, True)
```

Please rectify or suggest a better way. Regards.

Comment: The CellTemplate is used for *new* cells.  You no doubt want to change the borderstyle of *existing* cells.  Use the Cells property.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub dgvLegends_CellPainting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles dgvLegends.CellPainting
    'Draw custom cell borders.
    'If current column is DisplayName...
    If dgvLegends.Columns("DisplayName").Index = e.ColumnIndex AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim Brush As New SolidBrush(dgvLegends.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush, e.CellBounds)
            Brush.Dispose()
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All And Not DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground)

            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.CellBounds, dgvLegends.GridColor, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, dgvLegends.GridColor, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, dgvLegends.GridColor, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, dgvLegends.GridColor, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)

        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

try css?

```
    .style1 
    {
        border:none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .style1 td+td
    {
        border:1px solid red;
    }

 <table cellpadding="2" class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td>a
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>d
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>c
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```